# Dependency error when running React on AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, dependencies, aws-amplify

Recently after installing react-collapsed package with npm there was no issue with running on localhot and everything was as expected. However after building on AWS Amplify I encountered the following dependency error. I've tried `npm ci` to clean up the dependencies with no luck. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

```
2023-02-03T05:34:40.280Z [WARNING]: ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
                                    npm ERR!
2023-02-03T05:34:40.280Z [WARNING]: npm ERR! While resolving: react-collapsed@3.6.0
                                    npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
                                    npm ERR! node_modules/react
                                    npm ERR!
2023-02-03T05:34:40.281Z [WARNING]: react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
                                    npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
                                    npm ERR!   node_modules/react-dom
                                    npm ERR!     react-dom@"^18.2.0" from the root project
                                    npm ERR!   3 more (react-router, react-router-dom, react-scripts)
                                    npm ERR!
                                    npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
                                    npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8 || ^17" from react-collapsed@3.6.0
2023-02-03T05:34:40.281Z [WARNING]: npm ERR! node_modules/react-collapsed
                                    npm ERR!   react-collapsed@"^3.6.0" from the root project
                                    npm ERR!
                                    npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
                                    npm ERR! node_modules/react
                                    npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8 || ^17" from react-collapsed@3.6.0
                                    npm ERR!   node_modules/react-collapsed
                                    npm ERR!     react-collapsed@"^3.6.0" from the root project
                                    npm ERR!
2023-02-03T05:34:40.281Z [WARNING]:
```

Tried uninstalling which reverted the issue, npm ci didn't resolve the issue

Comment: i wonder if npm audit would work for you? I dont think it aligns packages but it could be worth a shot locally first.

Comment: Unfortunately audit didn't help, same issue persists

Comment: could you please try npm install with --legacy-peer-deps

Comment: No luck on that front, I originally installed with legacy deps as well

Comment: After uninstalling react-collapsed it went back to normal, I suspect it might have something to do with an incompatibility between collapsed and the version of react amplify is using

Comment: If you are on NPM > 8 then you can use overrides.

  "overrides": {
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": {
      "@radix-ui/react-accordion": "1.0.0",
      "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "1.0.0",
      "@radix-ui/react-slider": "1.0.0",
      "@radix-ui/react-tabs": "1.0.0"
    }
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging it appears that react-collapsed removed support for react 18 temporarily: https://github.com/roginfarrer/collapsed/pull/120. Rolling back to react-collapsed@3.0 solved the issue